# Python Seaborn displot with array of constant values

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a problem using seaborn.distplot with an array of constant values.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.distplot([1] * 10)
```

Returns:

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

-- EDIT: new version of Seaborn (0.6.0) solves the problem

The previous problem happened with seaborn version 0.5.1. Solved with version 0.6.0.

Comment: Your question does not provide enough information (i.e. versions, etc) but I cannot reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the same value for all items in the data. Because there is no variance between the lower and upper values in the range (or the 1st and 3rd quartiles depending on how the bins are calculated), the bins become undefined i.e. `nan`. This can not be converted to an integer and is the cause of the exception that you see. Possibly that is a bug in seaborn - at least it could be better handled.

You might have better success with this:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.distplot([1,2] * 10)
```

Comment: I realize the error stems from constant values. Actually I call `sns.distplot` within `sns.FacetGrid().map` and only one variable is constant which makes plotting fail... I wish `sns.distplot` could handle constant values!